# How can I configure chrome to use forward and back mouse click actions, like in Opera?

Tags: google-chrome, opera

In Opera, when you hold left-click and right-click, you move forward. When you do the opposite, you move back. Is there a way to configure chrome to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Smooth Gestures](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/lfkgmnnajiljnolcgolmmgnecgldgeld) extension. Looks like it's extremely customizable.

Comment: The gestures to map are "Rocker Left" and "Rocker Right", which are both set via performing the actual mouse gestures. This was very easy to setup and use.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked several extensions and finally chose **Gestures for Chrome (TM)** as the most convenient and bugfree widget.